# Getting "Redirect loop error" in Laravel 5.1 with auth middleware

Tags: php, loops, laravel, authentication, redirect

Here is my routes.php file:

```
Route::get('/',['domain' => 'admin.myapp.com','middleware' => 'auth','uses' => 'GameController@add']);
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
    ]);

Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
```

Each time I try to access

```
admin.myapp.com
```

it redirects me to

```
http://admin.myapp.com/auth/login
```

and says

```
This webpage has a redirect loop

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

When I added

```
Route::get('/',['domain' => 'admin.myapp.com','uses' => 'GameController@add']);
```

without the

```
'middleware' => 'auth'
```

it works, but I need to make accessing

```
http://admin.myapp.com
```

for authenticated users only.

Here is my **.htaccess** file contents in the app root dir

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myapp\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.myapp\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/myapp\.com" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.myapp\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.admin\.myapp\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/admin\.myapp\.com" [R=301,L]
```

On the local server, I created a virtual host and used it as the sub-domain in the routes.php file and worked perfectly.
As hazem.dev domain goes to the controller GameController@add and the localhost/myapp goes to the HomeController@index, both for the '/' route.

Why it is not working on the online server ?
So what is the reason for this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably because you have insufficient permissions on your online server when it comes to writing to `storage`. Always mirror your development and live environment so you won't get screwed like this.

Comment: What do you mean with **writing to storage** ?

Comment: `storage` is a directory where Laravel writes logs and other stuff. Your PHP probably has no permissions to write there. Check your server log for detailed explanation.

Comment: So you suggest that I set the application's environment to **production** ?

Comment: I set the application to the production mode but the problem still exists.

Comment: No, I suggest that you inspect server logs to see what happens and the other thing I'm suggesting is, if I am right - alter the permissions for the `storage/` directory so that PHP can write to it.

Comment: I set its permission to 777.
Here is a line of the log file located in the /home/myusername/logs directory

MY_IP_ADDRESS - - [14/Aug/2015:04:54:13 -0700] "GET /auth/login HTTP/1.0" 301 245 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36"

This line is repeated so many times, I don't think it says something important.

Comment: That's the access log, not error log. Your Laravel produces an error and then goes into redirect loop.

Comment: I viewed the laravel log file, it did not mention the redirect loop issue.

Comment: Ok, I'll try one last time - your **web server** contains a log file too. You never mentioned what the web server you use was, you didn't mention whether you serve php via `php-fpm` or something else so no one can tell you **where the log is**. I'll leave you with that, I sincerely wish you all the luck resolving your problem.

Comment: I have the app hosted on a Godaddy shared hosting.

Comment: I've added the contents of my **.htaccess** file to the topic, please review it as it may help :)